# In plotly I have 2 horizontal bars, how to close gap vertically between them?

Tags: python, graph, plotly-python

I want a graph that look a lot slimmer without giving the user the ability interact with it. I made the bars slim but the gap between them is too big!

This is the code:

```
config = {'displayModeBar': False, 'responsive': False}

categories = ['Category 1', 'Category 2']
values = [202, 310]

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    y=categories[::-1],
    x=values[::-1],
    text=values,
    orientation='h',
    width=0.1,
    marker_color='rgba(81, 132, 4, 1)',
    textposition = 'outside'
))

fig.update_layout(
    dragmode=False,
    hovermode=False,
    margin=dict(t=0, b=0),
    autosize=True,
    barmode='stack',
    plot_bgcolor='white',
    xaxis=dict(
        showticklabels=False
    ),
    bargap = 0.1
)
print(opy.plot(fig, output_type='div', config=config))
```

This is the output:
[image]

I just want the them to be closer to each other. Is it even possible?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62925197/12621346)